# Cannot start MongoDB on WSL

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mongodb

I have installed MongoDb, **on WSL** using the steps from the official docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

When i issue the command
`sudo service mongod start`
i get the following message
`mongod: unrecognized service`.

I've tried troubleshooting using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885820/how-to-check-the-version-before-install-packages-using-apt-get) stackoverflow answers. 
I got it starting using one of the commands 
`sudo mongod --fork -f /etc/mongod.conf`

However I cannot stop mongod using `sudo service mongod stop`. In fact mongod keeps running even after i close WSL. Is the documentation wrong? Or am i doing something wrong?
Why wont the commands listed in the docs work?

If I keep using the above command to start mongodb will it affect the data that i store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very important (blockquoted with a red background, no less!) excerpt from the exact link to the MongoDB docs you gave:

> MongoDB does not support the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

However, it should still work, they just won't support it and the version they provide in the package `mongodb-org` won't work right. I suggest following Microsoft's guide [located here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/databases) which is part of a larger Python guide. Find the "Install MongoDB" section about halfway down the page. Note that the service is named `mongodb` here and not `mongod`.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix the

> mongod: unrecognized service

issue by performing the following tasks:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/mongod
```

then copy and paste the content from [this url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/mongo/master/debian/init.d) and save it (you can use vim or any other text editor)

After that give executable permission

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mongod
```

Now you will be able to start the service by following command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: This works with the installation instructions in the official MongoDB documents which install the mongodb-org package. You need the additional instructions if you are using WSL Ubuntu because somehow the service is not created.


Doing "sudo apt-get install mongodb" installs a totally seperate MongoDB package, which may not be as updated as the official one.

Comment: @AaronGong you are absolutely right

Comment: confirming this works with latest official instructions for mongo 4.4, wsl2 and ubuntu 20.

Comment: in the latest wsl2, if i could not find the daemon `mongd` instead tried `mongodb` and it worked, also the file was already there in `etc/init.d/mongodb` not needed to copy it from the github. Thanks :)

Comment: tried this but it fails.

[sudo] password for deepak: 
 * Starting database mongod                                                                                                         [fail]